# How to use pyqt evaluate javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, spidermonkey

I am learning pyqt,use for parse webpage.

Now i want use pyqt evaluate javascript function just like this answer do: 
[spidermonkey evaluate js function which in remote js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931688/how-to-load-remote-javascript-into-a-spidermonkey-context)

```
import urllib2
import spidermonkey
js = spidermonkey.Runtime()
js_ctx = js.new_context()
script = urllib2.urlopen('http://etherhack.co.uk/hashing/whirlpool/js/whirlpool.js').read()
    js_ctx.eval_script(script)
    js_ctx.eval_script('var s = "abc"')
    js_ctx.eval_script('print(HexWhirlpool(s))')
```

I want know how to achieve the same effect by using pyqt instead of spidermonkey.

Comment: Please be more specific on what is it exactly that you are trying to achieve, and if possible, add some example code to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PyQt` is a UI framework, so it might not be the best arrow in your quiver.

You can use [WebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qml-qtwebkit3-webview.html) to load and display the web page. Since `WebView` uses WebKit, it will load and parse the HTML and all CSS and JavaScript in it. But that means you just get the final result - you don't have much control what is loaded and when.

Or you can use a tool like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML. This gives you full control. You can then try to use `spidermonkey` to run the JavaScript but that will fail since many global variables like `window` or `document` will be missing. Also, there won't be a DOM.

For this, you'd need something like [Envjs](https://github.com/thatcher/env-js) but [there is no Python integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188541/using-env-js-with-python).

Maybe PhantomJS (a script driven Chrome/Chromium browser) is an option. See this question: [Is there a way to use PhantomJS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much,It is of great help to me.